# Python: How to pass variables into decorators AND decorators pass decorator variables back into function as well?

Tags: python, decorator

I am always looping through the files of a directory to perform various kinds of data manipulations.
Thus, I always use the following code

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_):
    for file_name in files:
        # manipulations here
```

Instead of keep writing these lines of code for every function, I was wondering if I can make it better by using decorators. Like the following:

```
# decorator
def wrapper_layer1(directory):
    def wrapper_layer2(func):
        def wrapper_layer3(*args, **kwargs):
            for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_):
                for file_name in files:
                    func(subdir, dirs, files, file_name)
            return wrapper_layer3
        return wrapper_layer2
    return wrapper_layer1

# function
@wrapper_layer1(dir_=r"")
def func(subdir, dirs, files, file_name):
    # manipulations here
```

I have found many resources out there which focus on how to pass parameters into the decorator.
But in this case, it requires not only pass parameters into the decorator, also require decorator pass parameters to function.

Does anyone know how to achieve?

Comment: What is not working with that?

Comment: The 2nd block of code demonstrates what I want to do, but actually it doesn't work LOL

Comment: What does it do? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It runs without any error, but no output as well.
So I am not sure how to make it work

Comment: Well you never call `func`, so ofc you're not getting any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that takes arguments for the decorator function (`wrapper_layer1` in your example) should return the decorator function, not itself. Similarly, the decorator function (`wrapper_layer2` in your example) should return the wrapper function, not itself. And finally, the wrapper function (`wrapper_layer3` in your example) should return something other than itself to the caller, if at all:

```
def for_each_file(dir_):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_):
                for file_name in files:
                    func(subdir, dirs, files, file_name)
            # return something meaningful, or don't return anything at all if
            # the caller does not expect a returning value
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few mistakes, now it works.
Thank you, guys, for pointing out my mistakes.

Here is what works for me.

```
# decorator
def wrapper_layer1(directory):
    def wrapper_layer2(func):
        def wrapper_layer3(*args, **kwargs):
            for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
                for file_name in files:
                    func(subdir, dirs, files, file_name)
        return wrapper_layer3
    return wrapper_layer2

# function
@wrapper_layer1(directory=dir_)
def func(subdir, dirs, files, file_name):
    print(subdir)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
    print(file_name)


func(dir_)
```